# Lithium tags need to be looked at again

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a lot of lithium tags. We have [lithium](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium) [lithium-ion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium-ion) [lithium-polymer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium-polymer) [lipo](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lipo)

It looks like we need to clean up lithium and check to see if there are any questions that are on just lithium and put the rest of the lithium tags into other categories. I suppose a lithium-metal tag could be created if needed.

[lithium-polymer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium-polymer) [lipo](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lipo) should also be merged, since they are the same thing.

Also one thing that is really useful for looking at tags that need to be grouped is the related tags listed off to the right of the page when clicking on a tag:
[image]

Comment: Hi, lifepo4 = LiFePO4 Lithium Iron Phosphate battery chemistry. More info [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate_battery). IMHO that one needs to stay on its own as it's different from other Li-ion tags. HTH

Comment: Then the tag should be LiFePo4

Comment: I would agree, but AFAIK all tags seem to always be lower case?! Here's a [Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216225/is-there-any-reason-why-tags-are-lower-cased) which seems to confirm that lower-case only tags are just the way it is.

Comment: I don't believe many people who would use the tag would necessarily know they're talking about LiFePO4.

Comment: @ScottSeidman - Hi, I really want to understand your point, but I don't get it. Are you saying that people use the lifepo4 tag *without* knowing that it refers to batteries with the LiFePO4 chemistry? (If so, why do you think people use a tag without knowing its purpose? Any idea?) Or is there a negative missing from your comment, and you're saying that the only people who would use that tag *would* already know what it means? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson. I just think that a big subset of users asking about lithium cell chemistry may not know the specific cell they're asking about, so they won't find the right specific tag, but would find a more generic tag like "lithium battery"

Comment: Note that the edit trail makes the comments pretty hard to follow, and I suppose I missed

Comment: You could always check the 4 questions to see if they are specific

Comment: At minimum we need to separate (regardless of actual tag name: (1) LiIon, Lithium Ion (2) LiFePO4, ... (3) LiPo , Lithium Polymer, ... || Lithium in its own right is valid for Lithium primary cells - rarer but non zero and quite different than the others. || LiIon and LiPo have much the same chemistries but the construction varies. || I don't see any great problem having the 4 types differentiated. || I'd be surprised if Scott was correct re LiFePO4 - he may be. I have seen SOME confusion here and elsewhere between LiFePO4 and other Lixxx types but its minimal. ...

Comment: ... LiFePO4 has substantial differences from the other Li secondary cells.